# Installing Python 2.7 projects in a system with Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, setup.py, ubuntu-22.04

I've come to a delicate situation:

My company's projects are all based in Python 2.7 and use specific PATH and PYTHONPATH exports to get around each other. The new machine I received has Ubuntu 22.04 and Python 3.10 preinstalled. My previous used to have Python 2.7 and I just installed 3.x on top and it worked just fine, at the beginning. I ended up messing up all the version altogether and everything seemed broken. So now I'm cautious on how to proceed

I've watched numerous tutorials online about setting up a virtual environment and how 'easy' it is to work with multiple version but seems that don't do the trick.

I would like to set up a virtual environment in Python 2.7 where I can just

`python setup.py install ....`

with all my packages and install them using python 2.7
At the same time, I'd like Python 3 to be available (because I'm futurizing some of these projects) to also install them using Python 3:

`python3 setup.py install ...`

What is the best strategy to implement this on my machine? Python 2 looks like it's not installed at all. Should I just install it on top of 3.10 ?

Comment: If you find a Python 2.7 for your operating system, then it is safe to have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.10 on the same machine at the same time (you could also add Python 3.11 as well without issue), no worries about that. But yes you have to install Python 2.7 before being able to create a virtual environment for Python 2.7. The difficult part might be to find a Python 2.7, or maybe it is easy I do not know I never had to.

Comment: Seems like Python 2.7 is still available in Ubuntu 22.04 after all. A simple `apt-get install python2.7` should do the trick. Then you should be able to create a virtual environment for Python 2.7 and do your work in that environment.